# PostgreSQL Notice: word is too long to be indexed error

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I try to make a fulltext search with postgresql.

Query:

```sql
SELECT * ,
    count(*) OVER(order by id DESC) AS full_count,
    ts_headline(
        'english', 
        "content", 
        websearch_to_tsquery('test1 test2 test3 test4'), 
        'StartSel=<mark>, StopSel=</mark>, HighlightAll=true, MaxWords=35, MinWords=1, ShortWord=3'
    ) AS content_highlighted,
    ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english', content), websearch_to_tsquery('test1 test2 test3 test4')) AS rank
FROM book_c_bookitem bi
WHERE to_tsvector('english', content) @@ websearch_to_tsquery('test1 test2 test3 test4')
order by id DESC, is_latest DESC , rank DESC
limit 30
offset 0
```

When I search a word with `websearch_to_tsquery`, everything is fine. But when I try to search two or more words, I got error:

```sh
canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

How I can solve this problem?

## Update

Thanks to @LaurenzAlbe. I adding `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to query, I got this error:

`Notice: word is too long to be indexed - set successfully executed`

How I can fix this error?

Comment: Set `statement_timeout` to 0.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe after long time, no response.

Comment: Then the query probably takes too long. [edit] your question and add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query. Also, what indexes do you have?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe result: `Notice: word is too long to be indexed - set successfully executed.`

Comment: That means that there is a word in your text that is longer than 2047 characters. You'd have to fix that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks laurenz. I update question. Can you help to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I guess my comment was not clear enough. You cannot use full text search with such words. By "fix that" I meant to modify the data so that there is no word that is as long as that. What language is that anyway?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for reply. It's Persian words.

Comment: PostgreSQL full text search has no support for the Farsi language, so even if you avoid huge words like this, your experience won't be great.